# Find the value of $\lim_{x \to 2} \frac {xf^2(x)-9}{(x-2)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Suppose that $$\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{x f(x)-3}{x-2}=5.$$

Then, what is the value of $$\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{x f^2(x)-9}{x-2}?$$

Comment: You tried something?

Comment: $f(x)=5-\frac{7}{x}$ seems to satisfy the first limit. Then you can calculate the second limit yourself. Do you need just one $f$ that suffices? or all? or (dis)prove that there only is one?

Comment: The question was from my friend and I it seems to find the value of the limit if it is exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see that in $\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{x f(x)-3}{x-2}=5$, the denominator goes to zero. Since we have a limit, the numerator should go to zero too and hence

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 2}x f(x)-3 &= 0 \\
\lim_{x\to 2}x f(x) &= 3 \\
\frac{\lim_{x\to 2}x f(x)}{\lim_{x\to 2}x} &= \frac{3}{\lim_{x\to 2}x} \\
\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{x f(x)}{x} &= \frac{3}{2}
\end{align}$$

Then the limit of $f(x)$ at $x=2$ will be

$$\lim_{x\to 2}f(x)=\frac{3}{2}$$

and then we can conclude that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 2}f(x) \cdot \lim_{x\to 2}f(x) &= \frac{3}{2} \cdot \frac{3}{2} \\
\lim_{x \to 2}f(x) \cdot f(x) &= \frac{9}{4} \\
\lim_{x \to 2}f^2(x) &= \frac{9}{4} \\
\lim_{x \to 2}x \cdot \lim_{x \to 2}f^2(x) &= (\lim_{x \to 2}x) \cdot \frac{9}{4} \\
\lim_{x \to 2} xf^2(x) &= \frac{9}{2} \\
\lim_{x\to 2}xf^2(x)-9 &= -\frac{9}{2}
\end{align}$$

So we can conclude for the second limit that

$$\lim_{x\to 2^{\mp}}\frac{x f^2(x)-9}{x-2}= \pm \infty$$

as the numerator goes to $-\frac{9}{2}$ and the denominator goes to zero.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Set $x-2=h$

$$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{(h+2)f(h+2)-3}h=5$$

$$\implies(h+2)f(h+2)-3=5h+O(h^2)\iff f(h+2)=\dfrac{3+5h+O(h^2)}{h+2}$$

Comment: Sorry, what is the $O(h^2)$, Also, why you didn't sub. 0 instead of $h$?